# How to transform span bin information into separate bins?

Tags: r

I conduct an eye tracking experiment trying to detect the fixation distribution on two areas (Areas of interest, AOIs named "agent" and "patient") along the time. I have divided the whole time into time bins and got the following list for example:

```
Stimulus   Participant   AOI name   Start_bin    End_bin   span.bin
E19AP          P01         Patient      2           6          5
E19AP          P01         Agent        10          14         5
E19AP          P01         Agent        14          22         9
E19AP          P01         Agent        24          30         7
...
```

To finish the analysis, I need to split the `span.bin` into separate bins, like the following:

```
Stimulus   Participant   AOI name     bin
E19AP          P01         Patient     2
E19AP          P01         Patient     3
E19AP          P01         Patient     4
E19AP          P01         Patient     5
E19AP          P01         Patient     6
E19AP          P01         agent       10
E19AP          P01         agent       11
E19AP          P01         agent       12
E19AP          P01         agent       13
E19AP          P01         agent       14
...
```

That means each row is a bin. Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve the problem with R?

Comment: Please put your code back as text instead of an image (the way you had it first was better).

Comment: no problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to get the bin sequence, and then `unnest` from `tidyverse` to complete the dataframe. The last line just drops the `Start_Bin` and `End_Bin` columns, if you want to.

```
library(tidyverse)

Stimulus <- c("E19AP","E19AP","E19AP","E19AP","E19AP")
Participant <- c("P01","P01","P01","P01","P01")
AOI_Name <- c("patient","agent","agent","agent","agent")
Start_Bin <- c(2,10,14,24,31)
End_Bin <- c(6,14,22,30,33)
span.Bin <- c(5,5,9,7,3)
df <- data.frame(Stimulus,Participant,AOI_Name,Start_Bin,End_Bin)

df$Bin <- mapply(":",df$Start_Bin,df$End_Bin)
df <- unnest(df,Bin)
df <- df[,-c(4,5,6)]

> df[1:10,]

   Stimulus Participant AOI_Name Bin
1     E19AP         P01  patient   2
2     E19AP         P01  patient   3
3     E19AP         P01  patient   4
4     E19AP         P01  patient   5
5     E19AP         P01  patient   6
6     E19AP         P01    agent  10
7     E19AP         P01    agent  11
8     E19AP         P01    agent  12
9     E19AP         P01    agent  13
10    E19AP         P01    agent  14
```